# Eclipse Plugin : build failed java.lang.NullPointerException error for an update site project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I have a plugin that i developed and a feature project which includes the plugin and its dependencies. I initially had the same null pointer problem when i was exporting the feature project as a deployable feature. I got past that by generating a ant build.xml. I wanted to do the same with the update site, but with no luck. I want to know why I am getting the null pointer exception upon building. Am i missing anything obvious? There is no message related to the build failure in the error log /problems view.

Comment: Show your code, without the code will be hard, it's gonna be bullets into the vacuum

Comment: The project just has a site.xml file. Here are its contents -  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
   <feature url="features/xxxFeature_1.0.0.qualifier.jar" id="xxxFeature" version="1.0.0.qualifier"/>
</site>  The xxxFeature_1.0.0.qualifier.jar is available in a different project, which i added in the overview tab of the site.xml. The plugin it self works fine when i run the plugin as an eclipse application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse will generate a p2 repository (aka an update site) when exporting from your feature.xml if you select the "Generate metadata repository option".

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_publisher.html

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/export_wizards/export_features.htm

Comment: I get the same exception even when i export a features.xml file to a deployable feature.

Comment: Eclipse should have generated a .log file with a full stack of that NPE. Search for it in your workspace or Eclipse/configuration folder.